# Need to prove all three statements relating to upper and lower bounds

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

I had this proof for the first one: Assume that S is a nonempty subset of bounded below. Then there exists an x in S such that x is less than or equal to s for all s in S. Then, we can multiply both x and s by negative one and we get -s is less than or equal to -x for all s in set S. Thus, we can conclude the set -S denoted by {-s:for all s in S} is bounded above. But my professor stated that it would be incorrect and that i should start by choosing an arbitrary element in -S and using it to prove -S is bounded above. [This image has all three proofs that need solving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCfwG.jpg)

Comment: If $S$ is a nonempty subset that is bounded below, it is indeed not necessarily true that there exists $x\in S$ such that $x\le s$ for all $s\in S$. Take, for example, $S=(2,3)$ or $S=\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots\}$. The definition of "bounded below" is that there exists $C\in\Bbb R$ such that $C\le s$ for all $s\in S$. Do you see the difference between this definition and your argument? Can you use this definition to complete the proof of the first statement?

Comment: Thank you, yes I see that the lower bound doesn't necessarily have to be in the set S, just that it's in the set of Real numbers. Would the simple fix be enough to make the first proof complete? essentially the set -S being bounded above by -C

Comment: Yes, I believe so.